# Finding position for named area or place in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am transitioning from ArcMap to QGIS.

In ArcMap the Find option and Location Tab, gives me the option to enter a Single Line Input to locate a map position for things like a River, Town or Lake.

In West Virgina I often am asked to find parcels of property of XX acres on "Buck Run" in Tyler County, or something similar.

How do I accomplish this in QGIS 3.x?

So far I have searched for Geocoding and Reverse Geocoding, but I may not be searching for the correct terms to accomplish a solution.

Comment: I should be specific in that although I am often trying to find a parcel of a certain size acres on (or in the area of) a place, the size is not part of this question.  I am only asking how to accomplish that same "finding of a location" in QGIS as I have often done in ArcMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a GeoCoding plugin which you can install from the "Manage Plugins" menu. This then adds an option to the Plugins menu where you can enter a text string. If more than one place is matched then a drop-down appears and you can select and then get zoomed to that place.

It uses the Nominatim service (which is based on OpenStreetMap) but if you have a Google API key it can use the Google Geocode service.

For example, a search for "Buck Run, WV" shows one in Tucker County and one in Jackson County. Is there one in Tyler County?

There is also a Reverse Geocoding option where you click a location and get back an address near that point.

[image]

Comment: Thought there was in Tyler County, but I know there is one in Ritchie County!
This answer helped me a lot, even though it did not give similar results as ArcMap.  Perhaps that should be expected! <smile>
I also see that another Geocode plugin looks maybe helpful too!  It is called Pelias.

I am currently playing around to see if I can get more full coverage to return good quantities and matches as ArcMap.

Comment: Reverse, (or forward, I am confused!) lookup on a point on Buck Run gives this address: County Route 74/9, Stanley, Ritchie County, West Virginia, 26415, USA

So why did that not come up in the hit?  Is it because the label on the waterway feature is provided by ESRI National Geographic basemap?